# How to pass DetailView parameters for child entities with CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, entity

I'm pretty sure this is something very basic but I cannot figure it out.

In my detail view, I use ObservedObjects to define the variables for every child entity, and display them. It works.

Eventually, it asks for me to pass a variable for the each `ObservedObject`. For the parent entity, I pass the variable defined within the `ForEach`. For child entities, I tried below approaches:

Created separate FetchRequests for each child entity, tried to pass the variables
Tried `ForEach(zip(sequence1, sequence2, id: \0.self)) { seq1, seq2 in`
Tried one above without the zip, and just the parent entity

Getting this error:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Here's the full snippet. It's for a dictionary-type app:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(zip(words, wordClass, example, exampleTranslation), id: \.self) { word, wordClass, example, exampleTranslation in
        NavigationLink(destination: WordDetailView(word: word, wordClass: wordClass, example: example, exampleTranslation: exampleTranslation)) {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(word.transliteration)
                    Text(word.word)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
}
```

Fetch Requests:

```swift
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Word.word,
                                           ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var words: FetchedResults<Word>
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \WordClass.wordClass,
                                           ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var wordClass: FetchedResults<WordClass>
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Examples.example,
                                           ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var example: FetchedResults<Examples>
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ExampleTranslation.en,
                                           ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var exampleTranslation: FetchedResults<ExampleTranslation>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap it as array, pass the words object for the identification and then access the elements like this...

```
ForEach(Array(zip(words, wordClass)), id: \.0) { element in
    //access via element.0
```

**Edit:** Use zip for two element and access the other via index if all array have the same size. Not sure, if that is the case for you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var words = ["Test"]
    var wordClass = ["Test2"]
    var example = ["Test3"]
    var exampleTranslation = ["Test4"]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(zip(words, wordClass).enumerated()), id: \.0) { index, element in
            Text("\(element.0) + \(element.1) + \(example[index]) + \(exampleTranslation[index])")

            //<< Access first two elements via element tuple and other via index
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I get two errors on `ForEach` line: `Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`, `Extra arguments at positions #3, #4 in call`.

Comment: You are right... unfortunately zip only takes only maximum two arrays. There are libraries which support more. However, if the array have equal length you can also try to access the other via index. The above now should work, but only with two elements. I give you an update with index aswell

Comment: Thank you, I'll see what I can do further.

Comment: I have update the above code.. it works. Accessing the first two with tuple and the other with indexes. Do the array have the same size - then it should work fine